# Masonary js weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, css

There is a div in my masonary images and on 1920 resolution the div increases its height on some images and on few it acts same
for height I have used `height:intial;`

Any solution?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your sourcecode ?

Comment: Its actually in angular and content is added dynamically so i cannot